# Connect Retroflag GPi (Raspberry Pi Zero W) to WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi-zero, wpa-supplicant

I just got my retroflag gpi case working and set up. I have one small problem though. I can't connect my Pi to my WPA2-Enterprise network. I've tried a bunch of settings in wpa_supplicant.conf but can't get it to work.

**Pi Model or other hardware:** Raspberry Pi Zero W & Retroflag GPi Case

**Power Supply used:** Retroflag GPi's inbuilt.

**RetroPie Version Used:** 4.6.1

**Built From:** https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/releases/download/4.6/retropie-buster-4.6-rpi1_zero.img.gz

**USB Devices connected:** Retroflag GPi

**Controller used:** Retroflag GPi

**Error messages received:**
Can't see any error messages. Don't know where they appear. It just says IP-address Unkown in show ip.

**Guide used:** Several on Google. This one among others: https://gist.github.com/elec3647/1e223c02ef2a9a3f836db7984011b53b.
This one for documentation: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

**File:** /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

**Attachment of config files:** (wpa_supplicant.conf)

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=SE

ap_scan=1

network={
  ssid="Wifi-Name"
  scan_ssid=1
  identity="myusername"
  password="mypassword"
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  eap=TTLS
  phase1="peapver=0 peaplabel=1"
  phase2="autheap=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I actually solved it just now.**

For anyone wondering I managed to connect to the network on another machine (Ubuntu) and used Network Manager. I then checked the log (according to [this link](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2013-June/msg00126.html)) with the command:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager
```

This gave me this config for wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
country=SE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

ap_scan=1

network={
  ssid="Wifi-Name"
  scan_ssid=1
  bgscan="simple:30:-65:300"
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256
  password="password"
  eap=PEAP
  fragment_size=1266
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  identity="username"
  proactive_key_caching=1
}
```

**This might not work for everyone** else since the configs are always different for every network. So be sure to do the same steps as I did if you can't get it to work.

So glad I finally got this, haha.